# How does "Visits Per Day" get tracked?

Tags: discussion

We are one day before the StackExchange team will determine the fate of the Substrate StackExchange.

For context, we launched on the same day as the Proof Assistants site (which is already in public beta):

[image]

Our site still remains in private beta:

[image]

What doesn't make sense to me is the final "visits/day" number.

The Substrate StackExchange has an equivalent number of users, but has 8x more questions per day, 7x more answers per day (based on answer ratio), and a higher percentage of answered posts.

This implies there are a total of ~110 questions on Proof Assistants, and over 900 questions on Substrate, yet the tracking claims they are getting more traffic?

Is this due to the beta status and not being put on search engines?

Are there any insights that can explain this?

What counts as a visit? Is it per IP address per day?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66896/208518) mentions that this number comes directly from the Google Analytics API.

As you mentioned, the difference between Proof Assistants's number and Substrate's might indeed be the fact that the former is listed in search engines while this latter isn't.

Comment: I would assume most people use some form of Adblock - which blocks Google Analytics by default :-(

Comment: Yep, adblock here (uBlock Origin + pihole DNS)